# Laravel Check if a property exist in a collection within foreach

Tags: php, laravel

I have a generic form that I pass different collection to, from different tables. They basically have "name", and "id" properties.
Some of the collections have the property "description" and some don't.
How do I cater for that in my laravel view? I want both the **table heading** and **table body** to be displayed dynamically.

Please see my code below

```
    <tr >
      <th>S/N</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      @if($records->description)
      <th>Description</th>
      @endif
      <th>Date Created</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
```

```
    @foreach($records as $record)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$loop->iteration}}</td>
        <td>{{$record->name}}</td>
        @if($record->description)
        <td>{{$record->description}}</td>
        @endif
        ...
    <tr>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: Suppose, you have 100 row from in foreach, and only 1 row has `{{ $record->description }}` and 99 has null. Then?

Comment: @STA I just edited the question for clarity

Comment: Is there a situation you would have columns ABC for 1 record and ABD for another? Or is 1 alway a superset of the other? That changes my solution a little.

Comment: @onlineThomas Yes there are situations like that

Answer (score 0):

I typically use an `isset()` so it's clear what i'm doing but you could also use `??`.

For example:

```
@if (isset($record->description) && $record->description) @endif
```

Or

```
{{ $record->description ?? '' }}
```

Comment: Do you want to run a `forach loop` in table header?

Answer (score 0):

You can use helper function

array_get($record, 'description', 'no description');

here third argument is default value if **description** is not found in **$record**

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$headers = [];

foreach ($records as $record) {
 foreach ($record as $key => $value) {
    if (!array_key_exists($key, $headers)) {
        $headers[] = $key; // add header if not already in array
    }
 }
}

foreach($headers as $header) {
    <th>{{ $header }} </th>
}

foreach($records as $record) {
    foreach($headers as $header) {
        if (array_key_exists($header, $record)) {
            <tr>{{ $record[$header] }} </tr>
        } else {
            <tr></tr>
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as I understand you want to display your table dynamically, and that means if the column `description` had any value other than null you want to display it in the table header and of course display values in table body, so you have to do something like:
(i assume that you column `description` are nullable() so the default value is null)

```
   <tr>
      <th>S/N</th>
      <th>Name</th>

      @if($records->where('description','!==',null)->count() > 0)
       {{ $display=true }}
      <th>Description</th>
      @endif

      <th>Date Created</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
```

and

```
@foreach($records as $record)
<tr>
    <td>{{$loop->iteration}}</td>
    <td>{{$record->name}}</td>
    @if($display==true)
    <td>{{$record->description}}</td>
    @endif
    ...
<tr>
@endforeach
```